# Speed of [].forEach.call(...?

Tags: javascript, foreach, call, nodelist

I'm a big fan of using the forEach method on nodeLists like this:

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".foo");

[].forEach.call(nodes, function (item) {
    //do stuff with item
});
```

I was wondering though, does doing it that way take longer than the regular way?
e.g.

```
for(var i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){
    //do stuff with nodes[i];
}
```

Comment: BTW `for(var i=0, el; el = nodes[i]; i++)` works as well :)

Comment: Do you have a specific performance case you are trying to solve? Otherwise which case you might to avoid premature optimization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a [nice performance comparison](http://benhollis.net/blog/2009/12/13/investigating-javascript-array-iteration-performance/). According to it `Array.forEach` is slower than a native `for` loop.

Comment: Cheers, thanks for the link. That's exactly what I was after.
BTW, the jQuery.each speed is a bit surprising.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's an old post but using the forEach method can be done by stealing the Array prototype as well.

```
NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
```

Comment: +1 Doing this once, then having someNodeList.forEach() looks much neater than either using .call() for every loop or using giant ES3-style 'for' loops

Comment: But [the ES5 spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.18) says that "whether the forEach function can be applied successfully to a host object [like NodeList] is implementation-dependent." As far as a I know, Chrome and Firefox support forEach on host objects. I don't know about IE, Safari, Opera, etc.

Comment: It is implementation dependant but this won't make any difference to the implementation on browsers that have done so (I haven't actually found any yet, will try Chrome though.)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the browser. And don't forget about while() which is the fastest on Firefox 4. [Here's a comparison](http://jsperf.com/foreach-compared-to-for-and-while).

Also keep in mind that if you're supporting older browsers that don't support forEach, you need to add in the time it takes to [implement a polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/foreach#Compatibility).